# ASP.NET remove aspx extension where directory exists too

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I successfully removed the aspx extension but still have a problem if a directory exists with same name as an aspx file too. Example: domain.com/contact-us.aspx exists and domain.com/contact-us/ (folder) too.  In this way my rewrite rule force to the directory which not allowed to list the directory (but i want to the aspx file!).

What I am using in web.config:

```
<rule name="RemoveASPX" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)\.aspx" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" />
</rule>
<rule name="AddASPX" enabled="true">
    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx" />
</rule>
```